# IdentityServer3 organisation for multiple api

Tags: oauth, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have a DashboardApi and an EnterpriseApi on my system. May be one more later. 
I am new at IdentityServer3 and I wonder solve my problem. 
IdentityServer saves client applications that will use an api. So I have 2 or 3 api. Will I create IdentityServer for all api? Because DashboardApi will consume EnterpriseApi. EnterpriseApi will consume another api.
And users will login to Dashboard application. I could not imagine the organisation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: you may have one instance of IdentityServer being your identity provider/authority across different "resource" APIs as long as they all point back to that same authority when it comes to token validation.

Then an access token used for "DashboardApi" can be used by "EnterpriseApi". It is important to proxy the token properly and in my experience it would be advantageous to create different scopes for each API to have better access as to which calls may be used to proxy into the second API through the first (especially if user consent is a concern).

Comment: what do you mean by "proxy the token properly"?

Comment: @stombeur I mean that it is important to make sure that the same token sent to the user facing API (by the user, "DashboardApi") is forwarded to the backend API ("EnterpriseApi") as required by OP.

Comment: I only know of the 'trusted subsystem' approach to this (where dashboardapi acts as a client with its own credentials toward enterpriseapi). I would very much like to understand the approach you are suggesting, could you point me to some documentation on this? thanks!

Comment: Well it depends on whether the identity of the user is essential to the "EnterpriseApi" or any other APIs involved in the backend chain. I do not know of documentation of the sort but in a scenario using HTTP headers this would involve grabbing the Authorization header of the original request and making sure it is included in the request to the next API in the chain.